# How do I "name" columns/rows in pandas DataFrame for clarity?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to "name" the rows and columns in my pandas DataFrame, for clarity. I'm not sure what it's called, but I'm trying to create a table like this:
[image]

Is there an easy way to add "Actual class" on top of the column names, and "Predicted class" to the left of the row names, just for clarification?

Comment: As I'm googling, I can see that pandas has something called "multi index". Could that be used as a hack to create a table that looks kinda like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with `df`

```
classes = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit']
df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 2, 0], [3, 3, 2], [0, 1, 11]], classes, classes)
df

        Cat  Dog  Rabbit
Cat       5    2       0
Dog       3    3       2
Rabbit    0    1      11
```

#### `pandas.concat`

```
pd.concat(
    [pd.concat(
        [df],
        keys=['Actual Class'], axis=1)],
    keys=['Predicted Class']
)

                       Actual Class           
                                Cat Dog Rabbit
Predicted Class Cat               5   2      0
                Dog               3   3      2
                Rabbit            0   1     11
```

---

#### `pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`

Reconstruct

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values,
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Predicted Class'], df.index]),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Actual Class'], df.columns])
)

                       Actual Class           
                                Cat Dog Rabbit
Predicted Class Cat               5   2      0
                Dog               3   3      2
                Rabbit            0   1     11
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 2, 0], [3, 3, 2], [0, 1, 11]], classes, classes)` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame({
('Actual class', 'Cat'): {('Predicted class', 'Cat'): 5, ('Predicted class', 'Dog'): 2, ('Predicted class', 'Rabbit'): 0},
('Actual class', 'Dog'): {('Predicted class', 'Cat'): 3, ('Predicted class', 'Dog'): 3, ('Predicted class', 'Rabbit'): 2},
('Actual class', 'Rabbit'): {('Predicted class', 'Cat'): 0, ('Predicted class', 'Dog'): 1, ('Predicted class', 'Rabbit'): 11},
    })
```

[image]

Not sure it is a good idea, you create a MultiIndex just to clarify the representation of the dataframe as a string. You'll complexify the code for nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed create a multi-index:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np


In [2]: arrays = [['Cat','Dog','Rabbit']*3,
   ...:          ['Cat']*3+['Dog']*3+['Rabbit']*3]     

In [3]: tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

In [4]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Predicted class', 'Actual class'])

In [5]: index
Out[5]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit'], ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]],
           names=['Predicted class', 'Actual class'])

In [6]: numbers = [5,3,0,2,3,1,0,2,11]

In [7]: data = pd.Series(numbers, index=index)

In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame(data.unstack('Actual class'))

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
Actual class     Cat  Dog  Rabbit
Predicted class                  
Cat                5    2       0
Dog                3    3       2
Rabbit             0    1      11
```